# How to create a a column from a pandas dataframe with the repeated values in dictionary format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

i'm very confused on how to do this, (i'm very newbie yet) and I need to convert this dataframe into a dictionary with a column for repeated values:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [['John', 'hock'], ['John','pepe'],['Peter', 'wdw'],['Peter'],['John'], ['Stef'], ['John']],
                   'Age': [38, 47, 63, 28, 33, 45, 66]
                  })
```

and i need something like:

```
Name Age Repeated:
John 38  4
```

thanks!

Comment: Can you add some another row to expected ouput?

Comment: Do you mind to add the expected output? Why you add the Age as 38 if there are different Johns with different ages? What is the logic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of something like:

```py
resultDict = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for value in row["Name"]:
    if value not in resultDict:
      resultDict[value] = 0
    resultDict[value] += 1
resultDict
```

##### Output

```
{'John': 4, 'Peter': 2, 'Stef': 1, 'hock': 1, 'pepe': 1, 'wdw': 1}
```

If you want to have it as a dataframe and not a dictionary:

```py
resultDict = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for value in row["Name"]:
    if value not in resultDict:
      resultDict[value] = 0
    resultDict[value] += 1
pd.DataFrame({"Name":resultDict.keys(), "Repeated":resultDict.values()})
```

##### Output

| Name | Repeated |
| --- | --- |
| John | 4 |
| hock | 1 |
| pepe | 1 |
| Peter | 2 |
| wdw | 1 |
| Stef | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df.explode('Name').groupby(['Name']).size().reset_index(name='Repeated')
print (df)
    Name  Repeated
0   John         4
1  Peter         2
2   Stef         1
3   hock         1
4   pepe         1
5    wdw         1
```

Comment: Maybe the group by should be on Name only.

Comment: @rpanai - yes, but what happens with `Age`? Not sure, so waiting for OP

Comment: I asked him the same question ;)

Comment: Age in this case doesn't matter too much, it was more as an example of a given dataframe. sorry if I confused you guys. thx for the answers.